# How to insert an item in a database and sort again

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, sql-insert

Suppose I have a database with primarykey id and an varchar name, and I always need all my data ordered by id.

So the data is

1. james
2. jhon
3. patrick

and so on

And I want to insert a row in the second row

1. james
2. lee
3. john
4. patrick

How can I do it?

Do I have to update all the rows after "lee" and change the id?

Is there a simpler way to keep the order?

Thank you. I learn here a lot

Comment: is primarykey  `id` column `AutoIncrement`

Comment: This is a terrible database design, You can SELECT row_number() over (order by name) - instead and keep the id as the data was inserted. Changing primary keys like this should never happen. Imagine you have foreign keys pointing to your primary key, those would need to be changed as well

Comment: I can do the id AutoIncrement. It will help?

Comment: t-clausen.dk - I agree. it's seems to me strange as well, but how to do it?

Comment: Tables by definition are unordered sets. You do NOT insert rows into a particular position within a table. If you want results ordered you add an order by clause to your query. I can't really decided if you are wanting the table in a particular order or changing the primary key. Either way is a very bad decision and should not be done.

Comment: I don't want to change the id, and I don't want a particular order, I just want to have a way to select with "order by" with the order that the user gave me. I would take any suggestions that do the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to "insert a row in the second row"?  Doing that would indeed require you to update the other records, and you should not be changing the primary key values of your records. Changing them would also require updates in all tables that have foreign keys referring to this table.

Let your database handle your primary keys. If you need some number for some sort of priority or sorting purposes, I would suggest a separate column for that.

Comment: OK. so I add a new column - index. now I most update this column every time I insert a row. am I right? Is not there a simpler method?

Comment: No, you don't have to update them. just use a numeric or decimal data type for the order column. this way you can insert any row between any other 2 rows without ever having to change the other rows.

Comment: So if I understand correctly - I use a real number to the "index" column, and when I insert my row I select the row before and the row after and I fix the index between the 2 numbers. is it a normal way?

Comment: let's take the example in the question. you want to insert the name 'lee' to the second row. you do 2 things: first, get the index number of the second and third row, then insert your row with an index number that's between those 2 numbers. if, for example, the index of the first row is 0.1, the second is 0.2 and the third is 0.3, you can insert your record with any index number between 0.2 and 0.3. simple.

Comment: I thought about it. and it's not a good idea. after 10 inserts - the index will be 1.0001, and after 20 inserts - it will be 1.0000001,. the accuracy of a real number is not enough for that. I think it's better to update all the indexes